# Crystal Report Footer on last page

Tags: visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

I have been requested to make a Crystal Reports report using Visual Studio 2010, and the very last page of the report is what should contain some summary data. It is to contain nothing else, just some totals and maybe a chart or two.

How can I add a page to my report that displays that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `report footer` section.  If desired, insert a page break before the section starts to ensure that it begins on a separate page.